# XML DML (modify) in SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job, xml-dml

I'm trying to modify an XML value using [XML.modify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) in an SQL Server Agent job.  I'm using SQL Server 2008.  Here is my code...

```
DECLARE @temp XML;
DECLARE @newname VARCHAR(50);
SELECT @temp = CAST(ExtensionSettings AS XML) FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions] WHERE SubscriptionID = 'a2e1dd4e-5f65-4f0e-bc5a-8e58d21d7292';
SET @newname = 'Monthly_Data_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()), 120);

SET @temp.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value[../Name/text()="FILENAME"]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newname")');

UPDATE [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions] SET ExtensionSettings = CAST(@temp AS varchar(2000)) WHERE SubscriptionID = 'a2e1dd4e-5f65-4f0e-bc5a-8e58d21d7292';
```

This code runs fine if I just run it in a query window, but when I run it as a step in my job, the job fails.  The problem seems to be with the line...

```
SET @temp.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value[../Name/text()="FILENAME"]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newname")');
```

Because if I comment it out and run the job, it completes fine.

Can XML.modify not be used in a job?  What am I missing?!

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this the better part of today, finally post my question, and promptly found the answer!

I finally discovered how to view the job run history (right click on job, View History).  There it mentioned QUOTED_IDENTIFIER being set wrong.  A Google search later tells me that Agent jobs by default turn QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52802/sql-server-agent-quoted-identifier).

I added the line...

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

to my job's step and it started working!